# Set html/css clock time manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and javascript.
I have created css rotation clock as described in http://css-tricks.com/css3-clock/.
Normal case, this clock get local machine time using JScript Date().getSecond() method. Is there any way I can set time manually using hour/min dropdown using only javascript or jquery.
Here is the code for rotating clock hand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

          setInterval( function() {
          var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
          var sdegree = seconds * 6;
          var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

          $("#sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});

          }, 1000 );


          setInterval( function() {
          var hours = new Date().getHours();
          var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
          var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
          var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";

          $("#hour").css({"-moz-transform" : hrotate, "-webkit-transform" : hrotate});

          }, 1000 );


          setInterval( function() {
          var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
          var mdegree = mins * 6;
          var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

          $("#min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate});

          }, 1000 );


    }); 

</script>
```

I want to change Hour/Min variable using dropdown. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setTime(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    $("#hour").css({"-moz-transform" : "rotate(" + (hours * 30 + (minutess / 2)) + "deg)", "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(" + (hours * 30 + (minutes / 2)) + "deg)"});
    $("#min").css({"-moz-transform" : "rotate(" + (minutes * 6) + "deg)", "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(" + (minutes * 6) + "deg)"});
    $("#sec").css({"-moz-transform" : "rotate(" + (seconds * 6) + "deg)", "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(" + (seconds * 6) + "deg)"});
}
```

Should work but not tested it. Implement this to dropdown menu by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your solution seems very simple but i dont know how to get `hours`, `minutes` values from dropdown.